# Is the circle $(x+2)^2+(y+4)^2=4$ tangent to the $x$-axis? the $y$-axis?

Tags: geometry

I have the following question
[image]

As you can see on the image, the equation of the circle is $(x+2)^2 + (y+4)^2 = 4$

What I don't understand is how can I check the II. and III. propositions.
The answer sheet says that only the III proposition is true, graphing shows otherwise

[image: graphing]

How can I check the II. and III. options through calculation ? And not graphing? 
And why isn't the circle tangent to the x-axis?

Comment: You actually graphed $(x+2)^2+(y+2)^2=0$.

Comment: Your graph is wrong.  That circle in the graph is centered at $(-2,-2)$ but the equation in your prompt describes a circle centered at $(-2,-4)$.

Comment: On your question, put y = 0 i.e assume the x axis is tangent. What is x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a circle is $(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=r^2$, where $(h,k)$ is the center and $r$ is the radius. The [correct graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zs5wfg9uem) is a circle centered at $(-2,-4)$.

[image]

If the circle $(x+2)^2+(y+4)^2=4$ is tangent to the x-axis, then it must intersect or touch the x-axis. As $y=0$ on the x-axis, we need to satisfy $(x+2)^2+(y+4)^2=4$ when $y=0$. Substituting $y=0$, we obtain $(x+2)^2=0$ or $x=-2$, which is the point $(-2,0)$.

Then, since our circle is centered at $(-2,-4)$, it must have a radius of $4$ in order to be big enough to reach the x-axis. However, our circle only has radius $2$, so it cannot reach the x-axis. So, II is false.

III is true because the circle does touch the y-axis. When we substitute $x=0$, we obtain $(y+4)^2=0$ or $y=-4$, which is the point $(-4,0)$. As a circle is centered at $(-2,-4)$ and has a radius of $2$, it is big enough to reach the y-axis at the point $(0,-4)$. At this point, the circle will be tangent to the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If the circle is tangent to the x-axes, the the $y$ coordinate must be zero, this is impossible, then $$(x+2)^2+4^2\neq 0$$. The circle is tangent to the y axes is true, since we have $x=0$ then we get $$4+(y+2)^2=4$$ so $y=-2$

Answer (score 0):

The center of the circle is (-2, -4). So, the distance from the center to the $y$-axis and 2 and to the $x$-axis is 4.

Since the radius of the circle is 2, it is only tangential to the $y$-axis because the distance is the same as the radius.